# SPARQL parameterized queries

Tags: python, sparql, parameterized-query, rdflib

Good day! I apply rdflib for python. I have a question. How can I put variable into SPARQL's query ?
Instead of 'OSPF' in course:OSPF!

```
qres = g.query(
    """SELECT ?x ?z ?y
        WHERE {
           course:OSPF course:termName ?x.
           course:OSPF ?s ?t.
           ?s ?d ?z.
           ?t course:termName ?y.
           FILTER (regex(?z,"[^a-z]","i") && isLiteral(?z) )
        }"""
        ,initNs=dict(course=Namespace.....
```

@**msalvadores**
I want enter my Variable by console. --->python parse.py OSPF A value of variable(OSPF) may be another one. How can I initialize it into query(WHERE)? I have resolved my question by interpolation of variable several days ago. Like this:

```
    qtest = "OSPF","OSPF"
    q =( """SELECT ?x ?z ?y\
            WHERE {\
               course:%s course:termName ?x.\
               course:%s ?s ?t.\
               ?s ?d ?z.\
               ?t course:termName ?y.\
               FILTER (regex(?z,'[^a-z0-9]','i') && isLiteral(?z) )\
            }ORDER BY ASC(?s)\
            """)% qtest
   qres = g.query(q, initNs=dict(course=Namespace
```

But I suppose it could be done another way. Because on my opinion the solution is not quite right presented by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean a Python variable in the query you could do just ...

```
qres = g.query(
    """SELECT ?x ?z ?y
        WHERE {
           """+some_uri+""" course:termName ?x.
           """+some_uri+""" ?s ?t.
           ?s ?d ?z.
           ?t course:termName ?y.
           FILTER (regex(?z,"[^a-z]","i") && isLiteral(?z) )
        }"""
        ,initNs=dict(course=Namespace.....
```

If you want to transform course:OSPF into a variable in SPARQL then ...

```
qres = g.query(
    """SELECT ?newVar ?x ?z ?y
        WHERE {
           ?newVar course:termName ?x.
           ?newVar ?s ?t.
           ?s ?d ?z.
           ?t course:termName ?y.
           FILTER (regex(?z,"[^a-z]","i") && isLiteral(?z) )
        }"""
        ,initNs=dict(course=Namespace.....
```

If you explain a bit more what your query does and how your data looks like then we might be able to help better.

**Edited**

Only change that yo might want to do is to formulate the SPARQL query without repeating the variable, something like ...

```
q = """SELECT ?x ?z ?y
        WHERE {
           course:%s course:termName ?x;
                  ?s ?t.
           ?s ?d ?z.
           ?t course:termName ?y.
           FILTER (regex(?z,'[^a-z0-9]','i') && isLiteral(?z) )
        }ORDER BY ASC(?s)
        """%var_value
```

Notice the `;` at the end of the first triple pattern. I do not really understand the  `?s ?d ?z` pattern, I need to see some sample data. I suspect that you are trying to achieve too much with this query. If your dataset is big this query is going to be very slow. I cannot say more than this without seeing the data.

Comment: Thank you! I've corrected my code with your notation. It is really helpfully for me.

Comment: The assumption here is that `some_uri` does not contain SPARQL control characters (CWE-89). It can be dangerous to write SPARQL queries with regular string concatenation. http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/12147/whats-the-best-way-to-parameterize-sparql-queries