# Retrieve DBpedia page information automatically

Tags: database, sparql, dbpedia

I currently have a huge list of DBpedia pages of which I need corresponding data to be extracted (mainly dct:subject) from their respective pages. So for example, for the [Android_TV page](http://dbpedia.org/page/Android_TV) I need the following data (under dct:subject) to be returned as text:

- dbc:Smart_TV
- dbc:2014_software
- dbc:Google_software
- dbc:Android_(operating_system)
- dbc:Natural_language_processing_software

Now I know how to manually query this of course, but since I have a huge amount of these pages to query I need to find a way to do this automatically and have all this extracted information stored somehow. I of course have done a lot of searching on Google as well as Google Scholar, but I'm quite stuck.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Any useful papers / websites / explanations you might know of are very welcome! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This question is unclear to me. What do you mean by "automatically"? You already have the SPARQL query, right? Either you run a script like a Python script and run the query for each resource (what you call DBpedia page - in fact, this isn't a page...). Or you use the SPARQL 1.1 `values` clause, like `SELECT ... { values ?s {<uri_1> <uri_2> ... <uri_n>} ?s dct:subject ?subject }`

Comment: What I mean is that I have a list of different pages in the following form:
/page/Android_TV. Now for each of those pages I need their dct:subject information extracted. With automatically I mean that it's just too many pages to do by hand, so like you said I need some way to program this in Python. I just talked with my professor and he gave me the same two methods as you just did haha. Apparantly there is this python RDF library I can use for this, so I'm going to look into that now! Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: Ok. Just as a comment: `/page/Android_TV` is just the HTML rendering of the RDF resource. For information lookup, you have to use the proper RDF URI, i.e. `/resource/Android_TV`

Comment: Maybe you are likely looking for parameterized queries in Sparql like this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422401/sparql-parameterized-queries

Comment: How large is your list? Perhaps items of this list have something in common? For example, they are instances of `dbo:Device`?