# Sparql Query parameterized with string concatenation

Tags: python-3.x, sparql, rdflib, sparqlwrapper

I would like to write a Sparql query to obtain information about particular wikipedia articles. I'm a sparql newbie and could use some insights on using zlist as a parameter and passing it a list of articles, as .format would do in python.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?lemma ?item 
WHERE {
  ?sitelink schema:about ?item;
    schema:isPartOf <https://de.wikipedia.org/>;
    schema:name ?lemma.
  FILTER (?lemma IN (zlist@de))
}
```

For example, I tried this unsuccessfully:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
import pandas as pd
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
mylist = "Prato della Valle"

sparql.setQuery("""
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?lemma ?instance_of 
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 ?instance_of.    
  ?sitelink schema:about ?item;
    schema:isPartOf <https://de.wikipedia.org/>;
    schema:name ?lemma.
    FILTER (?lemma IN ( { %s }@de))
}                  
"""%mylist) 

results = sparql.query().convert()
results_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(results['results']['bindings'])
print(results_df)
```

However, I am able to get these to work:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
import pandas as pd

mylist = ["word2vec"]
mystring = '"' + '" "'.join(mylist) + '"'
# mystring = (' '.join('"{0}"'.format(v) for v in mylist) )

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql")

sparql.setQuery("""
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item {
    VALUES ?searchTerm { %s }
    SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:search ?searchTerm.
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
        ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
        ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
    }
    ?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
    }
    ORDER BY ?searchTerm ?num                    
""" % mystring ) 
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
results_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(results['results']['bindings'])
print(results_df)
```

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

my_variable = 'dbc:Meteorological_concepts'

sparql.setQuery(" ASK {{ {}  skos:broader{{1,7}} dbc:Medicine }} ".format(my_variable))
results = sparql.query().convert()
print(results['boolean'])
```

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
from string import Template

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")

query = Template("""
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    SELECT ?label
    WHERE { $uri rdfs:label ?label }
""")

sparql.setQuery(query.substitute(uri='<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Asturias>'))
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print (result["label"]["value"])
```

Note:[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827065/how-to-create-a-parameterised-query-in-sparqlwrapper-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58519010/constructing-graph-using-rdflib-for-the-outputs-from-sparql-select-query-with) and [also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422401/sparql-parameterized-queries) [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422401/sparql-parameterized-queries) and this [Github issue](https://github.com/gjhiggins/RDFAlchemy/issues/17) along with [this one](https://github.com/RDFLib/sparqlwrapper/issues/104) were most helpful.

Comment: This is typically called "prepared queries" or "parametrized queries". SPARQL itself has no functionality to do this - this would be a feature in whatever software library you use to create and run the SPARQL query.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback Jeen. I've been using python and sparqlwrapper. I read that sparqlwrapper doesn't allow for prepared queries and so I tried to create parameterized queries using rdflib per this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422401/sparql-parameterized-queries but am not having success yet. I wonder if it's possible to use sparqlwrapper and rdflib to carry this out?

Comment: If  "it doesn't work", then presumably the resulting sparql query is not correct. Without knowing what the error is it's hard to pinpoint where you're going wrong. Tip: print out the query string after injecting your list and check if it is syntactically correct sparql. I have a hunch that it might have something to do with the `@de` language tag in your query.

Comment: thank you for the tip reminder, that helped

Answer (score 1):

In this case, my list items needed to be in single quotes. And the { } around the variable in the FILTER line had to be dropped.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
import pandas as pd
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

preptitles = ['Prato della Valle']
mystring = ','.join('"{0}"@de'.format(w) for w in preptitles) 

sparql.setQuery("""
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?lemma ?instance_of 
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 ?instance_of.    
  ?sitelink schema:about ?item;
    schema:isPartOf <https://de.wikipedia.org/>;
    schema:name ?lemma.
    FILTER (?lemma IN (%s))
}                  
"""%mylist) 

results = sparql.query().convert()
results_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(results['results']['bindings'])
print(results_df)
```